# can't get this simple FOR LOOP code run correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to solve a simple coffee-shop puzzle,
the goal is to check if the item is in the menu and if I have enough beans after serving each drink.

I tried to console.log each row- and still I do not understand why it doesn't run as intended- somehow it goes into one if condition- and then goes also into the else.. what am i doing wrong?

thanks for your time

```
  `const coffeeShop = {
  beans: 40,
  drinkRequirements: {
    latte: 10,
    americano: 5,
    doubleShot: 15,
    frenchPress: 12
  },
  makeDrink: function (drinkType) {
    const drinks = Object.keys(coffeeShop.drinkRequirements);
    let drinkCost = coffeeShop.drinkRequirements[drinkType];
    let binz = this.beans;
    for (const key of drinks) {
      if (key === drinkType){
        if (drinkCost <= binz){
          coffeeShop.beans = [binz - drinkCost]
          console.log(`Good news! we have ${drinkType} and we have enough beans')
        }
        else {
          console.log("OUT of beans!")
        }
      } else {
        console.log(`we dont serve ${drinkType}`)
      }
    }
      }
    }
    // tests that wont run correctly:
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("latte"); 
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("americano");
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("filtered"); 
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("doubleShot");
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("frenchPress"); `

`see the console output I'm getting- its going the items again and again...`

`Good news! we have latte and we have enough beans
3main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve latte
main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve americano
main.js:322 Good news! we have americano and we have enough beans
2main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve americano
4main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve filtered
2main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve doubleShot
main.js:322 Good news! we have doubleShot and we have enough beans
main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve doubleShot
3main.js:328 Sooory Miss Sara- we dont serve frenchPress
main.js:325 Sorry Mam- we have frenchPress in the Menu - but we are OUT of 
beans!`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time that you loop over all the keys in the `drinkRequirements` object here,

```
for (const key of drinks) {
  if (key === drinkType){
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

you check a condition with each key in the `if` and `else` staments. Which will be `true` for one of the items in the loop, if the `drinkType` variable equals the name of your `key` value, but will be `false` on all the other occasions. You don't want that to happen on every key in the loop.

Rethink your logic. If you want to know if a string matches a key inside an object you can either get the key and check it for a value. Like you do here.

```
let drinkCost = coffeeShop.drinkRequirements[drinkType];
```

Or check it with the [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

```
if (coffeeShop.hasOwnProperty(drinkType)) { ...
```

Or even use the array of keys you already made with `Object.keys()` and use the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the key that matches the value of each drink.

```
const drinkRequirement = drinks.find(drink => drink === drinkType);
if (drinkRequirement !== undefined) { ...
```

Use one of these instead. Any of them is fine, though the first option might be the easiest one in terms of simpleness.

I disagree with @dave that you should replace `this` with `coffeeshop` as that will be hardcoding the coffeeshop variable in the function, although the missing backtick was on point. `this` will be the reference to the object the function is in. Meaning if you change the `coffeeshop` variable name, the reference remains the same.

```js
const coffeeShop = {
  beans: 40,
  drinkRequirements: {
    latte: 10,
    americano: 5,
    doubleShot: 15,
    frenchPress: 12
  },
  makeDrink(drinkType) {
    const drinkRequirement = this.drinkRequirements[drinkType];
    if (drinkRequirement) {
      const beansStock = this.beans;
      if (drinkRequirement <= beansStock) {
        this.beans = (beansStock - drinkRequirement);
        console.log(`Good news! we have ${drinkType} and we have enough beans.`)
      } else {
        console.log("OUT of beans!")
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`We dont serve ${drinkType}.`)
    }
  }
}
// tests that wont run correctly:
coffeeShop.makeDrink("latte");
coffeeShop.makeDrink("americano");
coffeeShop.makeDrink("filtered");
coffeeShop.makeDrink("doubleShot");
coffeeShop.makeDrink("frenchPress");
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer it's being very educating for a newbie like me- I went with your first suggestion and it works fine- I've also reverted back to using THIS of-course. cheers !!

Comment: You are welcome :). Please accept the answer if it answers you question so that others with the same question might be helped out.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance Sir - I really am a complete newbie in this community as  I've said :) ... button is clicked now. may you have Peace, Happiness -  and Health !

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
let binz = this.beans;
```

to

```
let binz = coffeeShop.beans;
```

and

```
console.log(`Good news! we have ${drinkType} and we have enough beans')
```

to

```
console.log(`Good news! we have ${drinkType} and we have enough beans`)
```

```js
const coffeeShop = {
  beans: 40,
  drinkRequirements: {
    latte: 10,
    americano: 5,
    doubleShot: 15,
    frenchPress: 12
  },
  makeDrink: function (drinkType) {
    const drinks = Object.keys(coffeeShop.drinkRequirements);
    let drinkCost = coffeeShop.drinkRequirements[drinkType];
    let binz = coffeeShop.beans;
    for (const key of drinks) {
      if (key === drinkType){
        if (drinkCost <= binz){
          coffeeShop.beans = [binz - drinkCost]
          console.log(`Good news! we have ${drinkType} and we have enough beans`)
        }
        else {
          console.log("OUT of beans!")
        }
      } else {
        console.log(`we dont serve ${drinkType}`)
      }
    }
      }
    }
    // tests that wont run correctly:
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("latte"); 
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("americano");
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("filtered"); 
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("doubleShot");
    coffeeShop.makeDrink("frenchPress");
```

Comment: Hi,I've tried your suggestions- but it keeps on iterating on items even after their IF condition is triggered...i have a major bug with the flow.